# Derivation of $\frac{d}{dx} \arccos{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am trying to derive $\frac{d}{dx} \arccos{\frac{1}{x}}$ and found a (rather longer than necessary) method below. I realise there are more concise ways, but I wanted to check the method below is technically correct, and interpretation of the $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $dx$ variables.

Starting with

$\cos{y} = \frac{1}{x}$

$y = \arccos{\frac{1}{x}}$

taking the derivative of both sides and expanding $y$ to $\arccos{\cos{y}}$

$\frac{d}{dx} \arccos{(\cos{y})} = \frac{d}{dx} \arccos{\frac{1}{x}}$

$\frac{d}{\cos{y}}\arccos{(\cos{y})} \cdot (-\sin{y}) \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx} $

$\frac{d}{\cos{y}} y = \frac{-1}{\sin{y}}$

$\frac{d}{\cos{y}}y = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1 - \cos^2{y}}}$

$\frac{d\cos{y}}{dx} = \frac{d(\frac{1}{x})}{dx}$

$\frac{d}{\frac{d(\frac{1}{x})}{dx}dx}y = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1 - \cos^2{y}}}$

$\frac{d}{dx}y \frac{dx}{d(\frac{1}{x})} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1 - \cos^2{y}}}$

$\frac{d}{dx}\arccos{\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{x^2}}}  \frac{d(\frac{1}{x})}{dx}$

Which is the correct answer. My questions are:

1. Is this valid? For some reason I thought we could not manipulate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ like that, but have since seen it done in my text book.
2. Interpreting $dx$, this is the arbitary choice of $\delta{x}$, and when we differentiate we take the limit to 0. But before we differentiate we can read this as some arbitary segment along x. Is this correct?
3. Similar, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the change in y w.r.t change in x when we make a small $\delta{x}$. As such $\frac{dy}{dx}dx$ can be interpreted as $dy$ because we are multiplying $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with are arbitary change in x, giving an arbitary change in y. Is this correct, is there anything further to consider?

Thank for your help

Comment: This is called implicit differentiation and is taught in many first courses.

Comment: You don't need implicit differentiation here.

Comment: After you change $y$ to $\arccos{\cos{y}}$, how are you going from one step to the next? The last equality is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I don't think so if we are talking about the same equality, $\frac{d(\frac{1}{x})}{dx} = \frac{-1}{x^2}$ so multiplied together gives the same answer as bjcolby15.

Comment: I know the last equality is incorrect, and @bjcolby15 made a mistake too. The derivative is supposed to be $\frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}$. And yes, we are talking about the last equality.

Comment: Personally, I am not happy with writing $\frac d{d\cos y}$. People abuse notation all the time, but to me this is absolutely abuse of notation. And what is the dot after it? You've lost me.

Comment: Thanks Accelerator I see now, have made the edit. Apologies Ted there was an error, it should read $\frac{d}{\cos{y}}\arccos{(\cos{y})}$, not sure if this is still notation abuse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1.$ Your answer is valid, if longer. From a purely technical standpoint, if you know the derivative of $\arccos x$, then the most concise way of getting this derivative is through the chain rule, rather than implicit differentiation.

$$y = \arccos \bigg(\frac {1}{x}\bigg) \\ y' = \bigg({\frac {-1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}}\bigg)\bigg({\frac {-1}{x^2}}\bigg) \\ y' = \dfrac {1}{x^2 \sqrt {1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}$$

$2$ and $3.$: You are correct.  If you use the definition of the derivative $$\frac {dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$ we can take $\Delta x$ smaller and smaller as $x$ approaches zero, and then we can call it $dx$ when it does approach $0$.

Thence we have $${dy} = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}\ dx$$

Comment: Thanks I appreciate this answer, though my question was specifically if that (worse) derivation is valid (or I broke the rules somewhere and coincidentally got the correct answer), and to check my interpretation of the variables in calculus.

Comment: Joseph - I've updated my response.  (I also see you've accepted the answer - hopefully my explanation helped!)

Comment: Thanks! That is very useful cheers, great to have confirmation am on the right track and interpretation of these things are correct, as well as having the much faster way of doing it. Cheers!